JavaScript Audio Streaming: CHUNK_DEMUXER_ERROR_APPEND_FAILED: RunSegmentParserLoop: stream parsing failed
Please I am building a chatbot and the Audio format is WebM Opus ... I am using a websocket to stream the audio chunks (after the response as been synthesized to speech) to my client js where I then append it to the source buffer. The issue is the first speech response I send after synthesis playback smoothly but when I try to append to source buffer for the next response I get the error : CHUNK_DEMUXER_ERROR_APPEND_FAILED: RunSegmentParserLoop: stream parsing failed....... Note I have tried doing source buffer remove(0, Infinity) after first audio chunks even did audio element.buffered.end(0).
///////////////////////////// Speech response /////////////////////////////

// Create a new MediaSource instance
var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
// Create an audio element
const audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
var updating = false;
var pendingAppendData = [];
var sourceBuffer;

let buffer = new Uint8Array([]);

async function websocketMessageHandler(event) {

  if (event.data.maxByteLength != 1 ) {
    // // Append new data to the buffer
    buffer = new Uint8Array([...buffer, ...new Uint8Array(event.data)]);

    if (buffer.length >= 512) {
      pendingAppendData.push(new Uint16Array(buffer.slice(0, 512).buffer));
      buffer = buffer.slice(512, buffer.length);

      appendData(); // Append the new data to the SourceBuffer
      if (audioElement.paused) audioElement.play();
    }

  } else {
    if (new Uint8Array(event.data)[0] == ControlMessagesEnum.END_AI_RESPONSE[0]){
      // pendingAppendData.push(new Uint16Array(buffer.buffer));
      // appendData();
      buffer = new Uint8Array([]);

    } else if (new Uint8Array(event.data)[0] == ControlMessagesEnum.START_AI_RESPONSE[0]){
        if (audioElement.currentTime != 0) {
          updating = true;
          audioElement.pause();
          audioElement.currentTime = 0;
          sourceBuffer.abort();
          sourceBuffer.remove(0, Infinity);
          // audioElement.buffered.start(0);
          audioElement.buffered.end(0);
          updating = false;
        }
    }
  }
}


// # add on message to ws.
function addOnWebsocketMessageCallback(external_function){
 // change websocket callback to include external function.
  async function on_websocket_message (event){
    external_function(event);
    await websocketMessageHandler(event);
  }
  ws.onmessage = on_websocket_message;
}

// Set the MediaSource object as the source for the audio element
audioElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
audioElement.onerror = (err)=>console.error(err.target.error);

// Listen for the 'sourceopen' event to create and initialize the SourceBuffer
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(){
  console.log('source is open')
  if (!sourceBuffer) {
  sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('audio/webm; codecs="opus"');
  sourceBuffer.mode = 'sequence';
  this.onsourceclose = ()=>console.log('them don close me oooo');
  }
});

// Function to append data to the SourceBuffer
function appendData(){
  if (updating || pendingAppendData.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  updating = true;
  const data = pendingAppendData.shift();

  sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', ()=>{
    updating = false;
    appendData(); // Recursively call appendData to process the next chunk
  }, {once: true});

  sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data);
}


The python code :
audio_format = "Webm24khz16bitMonoOpus"

@app.websocket("/voice_chat")

async def voice_chat(websocket: WebSocket):

    # print(websocket.headers)

    await websocket.accept()



    try:

        transcription = ""


        # for text to speech

        speech_synthesizer =TTS(text_to_speech_config, audio_format)


        async def finished_speaking(_):

            nonlocal transcription

            print(f"\n\nFull transcription from session: {transcription}")

            user_chat, ai_response = await conversation_handler_forAudio.chat(transcription)

            print("response .... ", ai_response)



            async def send_audio_stream(evt):

                print('sent audio bytes')

                await websocket.send_bytes(evt.result.audio_data)



            async def start_synthesis(_):

                await websocket.send_bytes(bytes([2])) // control byte to signal speech stream start



            async def end_synthesis(_):

                await websocket.send_bytes(bytes([3])) // control byte to signal speech stream end

 

            speech_synthesizer.onstarted(start_synthesis)

            speech_synthesizer.onsynthesizing(send_audio_stream)

            speech_synthesizer.oncompleted(end_synthesis)



           speech_synthesizer.start_speaking(str(ai_response.extracted_response))



I am expecting to be able to append the next audio chunks directly to source buffer because low latency is crucial. I don't want to create a new media source on every set of chunks.
